# Pipeline for more than 2 classifiers

Tags: python-3.x, pipeline, random-forest, knn

I am trying to build an ensemble using Knn and random forest classifiers.

```
steps = [('scaler', StandardScaler()),
     ('regressor', VotingClassifier(estimators=[
     ('knn', KNeighborsClassifier()), 
     ('clf', RandomForestClassifier())]))]
pipeline = Pipeline(steps)
parameters = [{'knn__n_neighbors': np.arange(1, 50)}, {
             'clf__n_estimators': [10, 20, 30],
             'clf__criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'],
             'clf__max_features': [5, 10, 15],
             'clf__max_depth': ['auto', 'log2', 'sqrt', None]}]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y.values.ravel(),
test_size=0.3, random_state=65)
cv = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=parameters)
cv.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = cv.predict(X_test)
```

I have encourntered the following error while running the above code:

Invalid parameter knn for estimator Pipeline(steps=[('scaler', StandardScaler()),
('regressor',VotingClassifier(estimators=[('knn', KNeighborsClassifier()),('clf', RandomForestClassifier())]))]). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`

Since I am new to machine learning I having difficulty in understanding the error.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the error message is not clear, but the error is raised because of the `knn` estimator in your `VotingClassifier`. Please check the `VotingClassifier` documentation:

> voting : str, {'hard', 'soft'}, default='hard'
> If 'hard', uses predicted class labels for majority rule voting. Else if 'soft', predicts the class label based on the argmax of the sums of the predicted probabilities, which is recommended for an ensemble of well-calibrated classifiers.
> (...)
>
> attributes : dict, default=None
> Dictionary mapping each estimator to a list of attributes to be extracted as predictors.
>
> If None, all public estimator attributes are used.

Concretely, `KNeighborsClassifier` has no `predict_proba` method, thus it cannot work with the `soft` voting classifier.
If you want to keep both estimators in your `VotingClassifier`, you should set `voting='hard'`:

`VotingClassifier(estimators=[('knn', KNeighborsClassifier()), ('clf', RandomForestClassifier())],voting='hard')`

---

UPDATE:- 20-05-2023

```py
steps = [('scaler', StandardScaler()),
         ('regressor', VotingClassifier(estimators=[
             ('knn', KNeighborsClassifier()), 
             ('clf', RandomForestClassifier())
         ]))
]

pipeline = Pipeline(steps)

parameters = [
    {
        'regressor__knn__n_neighbors': np.arange(1, 50)
    },
    {
        'regressor__clf__n_estimators': [10, 20, 30],
        'regressor__clf__criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'],
        'regressor__clf__max_features': [5, 10, 15],
        'regressor__clf__max_depth': ['auto', 'log2', 'sqrt', None]
    }
]
```

Comment: Still same error.